# Bullet Physics Applying Torques Effects not noticeable

Tags: physics, bullet-physics, torque

I am applying torques to a rag doll in order to make it move/walk.

For some reason, I am unable to view any effects when I use a call to rigidbody to apply torques even though these torques are pretty large i.e in the hundreds of Nm.

When I start the simulation, the doll just falls and the torques don't seem to have any effect. When I apply torque impulses however, there is a huge effect and the rag doll blows up because the angular velocity component becomes large that my velocity damping factor multiplies it and the torque impulse becomes huge.

I seem to notice effects of the torque though when I pause the simulation and then resume it after some time.

Am I missing something when I am trying to applying torques?
I know that when applying torque, it accumulates the torque value rather than updating the angular velocity directly.

I'm applying torques at every internal tick callback.

I'd be happy to supply necessary code.

Thank you all.

Answer (score -1):

The way I solved this was to apply the torques during the pre-tick callback for bullet physics.